Не передается coverage в SonarQube при выполнении конвейера из GitLab
Не передается coverage в SonarQube при выполнении конвейера из GitLab. Сама проверка выполняется, в Sonare есть результаты проверки, но именно coverage не переносится. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?
Часть файла gitlab-ci.yml
sonarqube-check:
  stage: build
  needs: [build]
  image:
    name: sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  variables:
    SONAR_USER_HOME: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.sonar"  # Defines the location of the analysis task cache
    GIT_DEPTH: "0"  # Tells git to fetch all the branches of the project, required by the analysis task
  cache:
    key: "${CI_JOB_NAME}"
    paths:
      - .sonar/cache
  script:
    - sonar-scanner
  allow_failure: true
  tags:
    - docker

Файл sonar-project.properties
sonar.projectKey=myapp
sonar.qualitygate.wait=false
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=./coverage/lcov.info

Часть файла vitest.config.ts
export default config({
  test: {
    root: fileURLToPath(new URL('./', import.meta.url)),
    coverage: {
      exclude: ['api/*', ...],
      include: ['src/modules/*', ...],
      provider: 'myprovider',
      reporters: ['lcov', 'text', 'html', 'clover', 'json']
    },

